# Replace original function inside its derivative

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, replacement, symbolic

I'm trying to simplify a derivative calculation. I have the `Zhs` in function of `x` :

```
Zhs[x] = Subscript[ζ, 3][x]/(1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x]) + 
  3*Subscript[ζ, 1][x]*
   Subscript[ζ, 2][x]/
     Subscript[ζ, 0][x]/(1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2 + (
  3*Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 - 
   Subscript[ζ, 3][x]*Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3)/(
  Subscript[ζ, 0][x]*(1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^3)
```

When I differentiate `Zhs` wrt `x` I get a too long expression:

```
-((3 Subscript[ζ, 1][x] Subscript[ζ, 2][x] Derivative[1][
    Subscript[ζ, 0]][x])/(
  Subscript[ζ, 0][
    x]^2 (1 - 
     Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2)) - ((3 Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 - 
    Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 Subscript[ζ, 3][x]) Derivative[
   1][Subscript[ζ, 0]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x]^2 (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^3) + (
 3 Subscript[ζ, 2][x] Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 1]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2) + (
 3 Subscript[ζ, 1][x] Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 2]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2) + (
 6 Subscript[ζ, 1][x] Subscript[ζ, 2][x] Derivative[1][
   Subscript[ζ, 3]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^3) + 
 Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 3]][x]/(
 1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x]) + (
 Subscript[ζ, 3][x] Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 3]][
   x])/(1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2 + (
 3 (3 Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 - 
    Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 Subscript[ζ, 3][x]) Derivative[
   1][Subscript[ζ, 3]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^4) + (
 9 Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^2 Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 2]][
    x] - 3 Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^2 Subscript[ζ, 3][
    x] Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 2]][x] - 
  Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 3]][
    x])/(Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^3)
```

`Zhs` should appear in its derivative expression. I'm trying to use `ReplaceAll` but it does not work, it gives me the same previous expression:

```
% /. Zhs[x] -> a

-((3 Subscript[ζ, 1][x] Subscript[ζ, 2][x] Derivative[1][
    Subscript[ζ, 0]][x])/(
  Subscript[ζ, 0][
    x]^2 (1 - 
     Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2)) - ((3 Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 - 
    Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 Subscript[ζ, 3][x]) Derivative[
   1][Subscript[ζ, 0]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x]^2 (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^3) + (
 3 Subscript[ζ, 2][x] Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 1]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2) + (
 3 Subscript[ζ, 1][x] Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 2]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2) + (
 6 Subscript[ζ, 1][x] Subscript[ζ, 2][x] Derivative[1][
   Subscript[ζ, 3]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^3) + 
 Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 3]][x]/(
 1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x]) + (
 Subscript[ζ, 3][x] Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 3]][
   x])/(1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^2 + (
 3 (3 Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 - 
    Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 Subscript[ζ, 3][x]) Derivative[
   1][Subscript[ζ, 3]][x])/(
 Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^4) + (
 9 Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^2 Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 2]][
    x] - 3 Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^2 Subscript[ζ, 3][
    x] Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 2]][x] - 
  Subscript[ζ, 2][x]^3 Derivative[1][Subscript[ζ, 3]][
    x])/(Subscript[ζ, 0][x] (1 - Subscript[ζ, 3][x])^3)
```

Does anyone know how to do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "Zhs should appear in its derivative expression"? Do you expect the expression to *factor* so that `Zhs` is one of the factors? Do you expect the expression to be a *polynomial* in `Zhs`? Or do you just think it should generically *simplify* if we write it in terms of `Zhs`? The problem here is that what you're asking for is not well-defined.

Comment: The derivative of  ```Zhs``` is a function of ```Zhs``` . I wanted such an expression.

Comment: You want a differential equation for Zhs ?

Comment: See my last comment. The point is that the *type* of function you might expect can determine the method used to solve your problem. In addition, do you mean that the right-hand side will be *only* a function of Zhs, in the sense that we can eliminate `x` from the expression by putting it in terms of Zhs? These kinds of clarifications would be useful.

Comment: I was expecting to obtain the derivative of ```Zhs``` in terms of ```Zhs, Subscript[ζ, 3], Subscript[ζ, 2], Subscript[ζ, 1] and Subscript[ζ, 0]```. Hypothetical example:   
```Zhs'[x] = Zhs + Subscript[ζ, 3] + Subscript[ζ, 2] +Subscript[ζ, 1] + Subscript[ζ, 0]```.   All ```ζ``` are also function of x.

Comment: Alright so what you want is to simplify your expression by maximizing the presence of Zhs in the expression via substitution. I will try a code I have.

Comment: @userrandrand, that's exactly what I want, Thanks.

Comment: I did not find much. Some parts can be simplified easily, some parts probably can not be simplified. I probably will not look into this more but if you want more help then I would suggest simplifying and clarifying the  question. First people often recommend not using Subscript other than for formatting via `Format` or something. Second the derivatives in `D[Zhs[x],x]` wont simplify without providing  a differential equation for them so you can simplify the problem to looking at only the terms that multiply these derivatives.

Comment: The code you can use to make it more likely that people will think about the question:

Comment: Thanks @userrandrand

Comment: say that you want to express `CoefficientRules[
 D[Zhs[x], x] /. 
   Thread[{Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Zeta], 0]][x], 
      Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Zeta], 1]][x], 
      Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Zeta], 2]][x], 
      Derivative[1][Subscript[\[Zeta], 3]][x]} -> {da0, da1, da2, 
      da3}] /. 
  Thread[{Subscript[\[Zeta], 0][x], Subscript[\[Zeta], 1][x], 
     Subscript[\[Zeta], 2][x], Subscript[\[Zeta], 3][x]} -> {a0, a1, 
     a2, a3}], {da0, da1, da2, da3}]`

Comment: as much as possible in terms of `Zv = Zhs[x] /. 
  Thread[{Subscript[\[Zeta], 0][x], Subscript[\[Zeta], 1][x], 
     Subscript[\[Zeta], 2][x], Subscript[\[Zeta], 3][x]} -> {a0, a1, 
     a2, a3}]`

Comment: Paste the `// InputForm` and `// TeXForm` of those expressions in you post to have a better view of what could be done. For the `TexForm` place the expression between `$$` and `$$` so that the mathematica expression renders on stack exchange

Comment: From trying what I noticed is that multiplying the coefficients  by `Subscript[ζ, 0]` or maybe  `(1-Subscript[ζ, 1])` makes the expressions look more like Zhs.

Comment: You might also want to consider a change of variables from `Subscript[ζ, 3], Subscript[ζ, 2], Subscript[ζ, 1] and Subscript[ζ, 0]` to another set of functions written in terms of those before taking the derivative to simplify the expressions.

Comment: Thanks for your help!